# virtual custom binding

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I have a scenario where i want to be abel to have a visibility binding.
And I want it to be virtual.

This fiddle solves my problem but I want a bindgHandler of it.
The problem I want to solve is that if a block property is true the elemnt should take up the space in the HTML, and I dont want to render unnessesery things.

http://jsfiddle.net/7ENpC/1/

I want to be abel to do this or nicer ofcourse.

```
<!-- ko foreach: allRows -->
<!-- ko visibility: $data-->
 <div>
   <span data-bind="text:text"></span>
 </div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

In the bindingHander all I do is

```
if(block)
   $element.css("visibility","hidden");
else
   $element.css("visibility","visible");
```

---

I cant get it right...can someone please help me in the right direction.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.visibility = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                var child = ko.virtualElements.firstChild(element),

       var visible = valueAccessor().visible();
       var block= valueAccessor().block();

   if (!block||!visible) {
       //call the general if binding ?

    } else {
      //Add visibility:hidden class 
    }

}
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.visibility = true;
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7ENpC/2/ updated to better show that number5 dosnt take up space.

Answer (score 1):

To make a custom binding able to be used as a virtual element you need to add

```
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.<your custom binding name here> = true;
```

So, in your case, you would want to do

```
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.visiblity = true;
```

into your code before you call `ko.applyBindings()`. See the [this documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) for more information.

Comment: yes i have tried that. But don't see how I should get the first element. And get it to work both virtual and not virtual.